# Array elements not getting edited in a Python List

Tags: python-2.7

```
sticks = int(raw_input());
stickList= map(int,raw_input().split()) ;
stickList = sorted(stickList);
for i in xrange(0,len(stickList)):
        stickList[i] = stickList[i]-stickList[0];
print stickList;
```

Given Input is :
6
5 4 4 2 2 8

Why the output is this: [0, 2, 4, 4, 5, 8]
instead of [0,0,2,2,3,6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are changing the value in source `stickList` in for loop.
After first iteration in loop `stickList[0]` will become `0` for remaining iterations.

As ShadowRanger mentioned reversed list will do,

```
stickList = map(int, "5 4 4 2 2 8".split())
stickList.sort()
for i in reversed(xrange(len(stickList))):
    stickList[i] -= stickList[0]        
print stickList
```

Comment: That doesn't actually get what he wants though. Operating on the list in reverse would though.

Comment: Deleted appending to list

Comment: Thanks @WoodChopper 
Just didn't realized that thanks

Comment: UW well it was shadows answer i actually posted new list with append

Comment: I submitted an edit with my intent (to operate on the `list` in reverse, not reverse the `list`, operate, and reverse again). An alternative approach is to generate a new list as a replacement with a list comprehension, which means the original `list` is available during generation, so you don't lose the `min` value while you're using it, e.g. `stickList = sorted(map(int, "5 4 4 2 2 8".split()))`, `stickList = [x - stickList[0] for x in stickList]`, `print stickList`